# How does screenshot in headless browser mode work?

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot, headless

I'm asking this question both out of curiosity and to add to my presentation I have coming up.

I have implemented a tool using .NET and it uses the Chrome's headless mode to take screenshot in specified resolution. I want to know how the screenshot is captured even though it is not presented on the viewport/display/monitor.

Comment: It’s not a *screen* shot. That’s all. // Browsers’ rendering pipelines are a highly complex topic. On a highly abstract level, there is no difference whatsoever between drawing on-screen and off-screen.